# Subdomain mapping to domain

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, a-record

What happens if you have 2 DNS entries:

```
Name         |  Type |  Value
-------------+-------+--------------
example.com  |  A    |  20.20.20.20
example.com  |  MX   |  mail.example.com
```

Does this mean that smtp requests to example.com will map to 20.20.20.20, and *somehow* request in the headers mail.example.com?  What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Mail Transfer Agent will request the MX DNS entries for the receiving domain (example.com) and determine the record with the lowest distance (priority or preference) (mail.example.com, although no preference is given in your example) and will look up the corresponding IP address for that record. The MTA will connect to the IP address returned by the DNS server to deliver the e-mail.

In your example you are missing a A record for mail.example.com and a preference for the MX record, but the notation of the preference depends on the used DNS software.

```
Name             |  Type |  Value
-----------------+-------+--------------
example.com      |  A    |  20.20.20.20
example.com      |  MX   |  10 mail.example.com
mail.example.com |  A    |  20.20.20.20
```

Comment: Worth noting that the record that the MX points to should ALWAYS be an A record, not a CNAME, because some poor, older MTAs will get stuck in a loop if an MX points to a CNAME.

Comment: Good point Farseeker. An additional AAAA (IPv6) record is also possible.

Comment: Also a lookup on 20.20.20.20 should return mail.example.com.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, also note that an MX record is not required. If there's no MX record, the sending MTA will look for a domain A record, and if it finds one, will send email to the ip address that the domain A record points to.

Comment: So the `mail.example.com` A record is not required?

Comment: Well, an MX record is not required but it is recommended. As you have it now, you have an MX record but no A record for mail.example.com, so in your case mail will probably fail to be delivered to your email server. You can do two things: 1. If your email server is at the same ip address that your domain A record points to then do nothing. 2. If not, create an A record for mail.example.com that points to the ip address of your email server.